# блок catch() не работает c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, try-catch

Здраствуйте!!! Использую в своей программе конструкцию try{}catch(){} и по какой-то причине при возникновении ошибке блок catch просто пропускается. Пишу на с++. Что мне делать?
Код:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <exception>
    #include <thread>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <exception>
    using namespace std;
    short* number;
    int main() {
        setlocale(LOCALE_ALL, "ru");
        try {
            printf("...");
            scanf("%i", &number);
        }
        catch (exception ex) {
            printf("error:%s", ex.what());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ***Какой именно*** ошибки? В функциях С? :) Что делать? Разобраться, какие именно ошибки приводят к генерации исключений, а какие тут в полной мере ни при чем... Кстати, лучше в `catch` использовать ссылку, а не значение.

Comment: Блок `catch` перехватывает не ошибки, а объекты-исключения, которые были созданы посредством оператора `throw`. В вашем коде `throw` нигде не используется.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с того что находится внутри try? printf и scanf, это си функции. В си не было исключений, так что логично, что эти функции не вызывают исключений.
Проверять правильность ввода в scanf() c использованием исключением можно так:

```
if (scanf("%hi", number) != 1) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Ошибка ввода числа");
}
```

Также я заметил неправильное использование типа исключения. Вы должны использовать ссылку на исключение (exception&), а не копию (exception), чтобы передать исключение в блок catch:

```
catch (exception& ex) {}
```

В итоге общая реализация будет выглядеть так:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    short* number = new short;
    try {
        printf("Введите число: ");
        if (scanf("%hi", number) != 1) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Ошибка ввода числа");
        }
    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        printf("Ошибка: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    delete number;
    return 0;
}
```

В комментариях пользователь AR Hovsepyan посоветовал не использовать в вашем случаи обработчик исключений из-за отсутствия нужды в нем.

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    short* number = new short;

    printf("Введите число: ");
    if (scanf("%hi", number) != 1) {
        printf("Ошибка ввода числа");
        delete number;
        return -1;
    }

    delete number;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут вообще нет никаких исключительных ситуаций, так что не имеет значения как будет правильно ее обработать.  Правильно _ просто без исключений

Comment: Ожидается числовой тип shot. В данном примере нет контроля нажатых клавиш, а значит пользователю нечего не мешает напечатать скажем буквы. Если такое произойдет, то scanf() вернет ноль, в if(е) мы это уловим и вызовем исключение.

Comment: `exception("Ошибка ввода числа");` - нестандартная фича студии. Правильно, например, `throw std::runtime_error("...");`.

Comment: Исключение не для того, чтобы ими пользоваться при каждой возможной ошибке.  Иначе все коды разбухать и замедлить можно в несколько раз. Не любая ошибка есть исключительная ситуация, из за которого стоит  замедлять код.  Это важное правило. В данном случаи простая проверка  в условии, гораздо логичнее. И  с  HolyBlackCat  согласен.

Comment: Проверка значения, возвращаемого `scanf` неправильная.

Comment: Спасибо, HolyBlackCat, я до этого даже и не знал о 'std::runtime_error'.

Comment: Спасибо, AR Hovsepyan, за замечание, хуть я и не сразу понял о чем вы. Дополнил ответ

Comment: user7860670, да, как минимум я не проверяю на допустимы диапазон значений у типа, но не думаю что вопрос об этом. Так что не очень хочется еще сильнее захламлять ответ.

Comment: Диапазон значений у типа проверить в принципе не получится, выход за его пределы для scanf является неопределенным поведением. Так что я не это имел ввиду.

Comment: Если нельзя, то на что указывал предыдущий ваш комментарий "`Проверка значения, возвращаемого scanf неправильная.`"?
В принципе можно использовать тип с большим диапазонном и потом сверять с `std::numeric_limits<тип с меньшим диапазонном значений>`(или в заранее прописать константы сверяя вы тоге сними) и если значение в допустимом диапазоне, то переводить собственно в этот самый тип (с меньшим диапазонном значений). Не знаю насчет правильности такого метода, но это всеже решает поставленную проблему.

Comment: Например, ожидаем ввод `int`, если введенное значение в диапазоне `[-32768;32767]` то переводит в `short`.

Comment: @pluto, функция `scanf` в случае сбоя может вернуть не только ноль но и `EOF`.

Comment: wololo, да, спасибо. Исправил. До этого я не встречался с таким значением. Буду знать